# Strangely copying and pasting a text in Jmeter is not working for in Mac

Tags: macos, jmeter

I can copy paste from everywhere except from Jmeter. I am using 10.7.5 OSx Lion and Jmeter version is 2.9 r14

Comment: I still experienced this issue on JMeter 5.5 and macOS 12.6. Solutions helped - switching to System theme or using Ctrl+V instead of Command+V.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Which Look N Feel are you using:

- cross platform
- Or System

See:
[image]

If using Cross Plaform switch to System.

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I was using Cross Platform switched to system and Issue Resolved!!.

Comment: For me this was due to opening jmeter from a tmux session.

Comment: For Windows, I had to change mine to 'Windows'

Answer (score 5):

Very strange.

But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste worked for me.

Comment: use ctrl+c and ctrl+v

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use  <kbd>cmd</kbd>  +  <kbd>c</kbd>  to copy from other applications and use  <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to paste to jmeter on masOS

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation