# Copy/Paste fails on MacOsX in JMeter

Tags: java, macos, jmeter, clipboard, copy-paste

I am having no luck using the clipboard to copy/paste text between other applications and JMeter or vice-versa. I am able to copy-paste text and test elements within JMeter.

I'm running JMeter 2.11 via the binary distribution by running 'bin/jmeter.sh' on OS X 10.9.1 running Java 1.7.0_45. I have attempted to use the clipboard with System and Mac OS X look-and-feels, per this previous question: [Strangely copying and pasting a text in Jmeter is not working for in Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986692/strangely-copying-and-pasting-a-text-in-jmeter-is-not-working-for-in-mac)

I have also attempted, with no luck, this procedure to grant system clipboard permission to AWT:
http://www.shodor.org/interactivate/resources/InstructionsCopyPaste/

Any advice on what I can do to get JMeter to share a clipboard with the rest of the system?

Comment: I have run the example provided below, and don't have trouble copying text from it and pasting it in other programs. It appears, then, that the trouble's with JMeter.

Comment: I am literally in the exact same boat as you, after upgrading to 2.11 from 2.9. I've tried everything I can find, but I haven't been able to fix it. I don't know if this helps, but I opened an issue: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56319

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy-paste behavior on Mac is much improved in JMeter 2.12.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this example from swing :

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/dnd/index.html#ListCutPaste

This is to see if it's a JDK issue on Mavericks or JMeter one.

UPDATE on 8 september 2014:
- Issue has been fixed, could you test [Nightly Build](http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html)

> Installing JMeter runtime
>
> Download the _bin and _lib files
>
> Unpack the archives into the same directory structure
>
> The other archives are not needed to run JMeter.

Comment: I have tried this, and successfully copy-pasted in & out of Swing.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue with JMeter 2.11.

I saw the error below when I attempt to copy paste.

2014-02-01 10:28:08.166 java[80082:2517] *** CPerformer: ignoring exception '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil' raised during perform of selector '_nativeGetTypes:' on target '' with args '(
)'

I stopped X11 (XQuartz) server in order to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Any time I try and paste copied text into JMeter from the OS I get the same issue. The same issue occurs when trying to paste into another application based on text copied in JMeter.

Copy + Paste is fine within JMeter itself (i.e. copy + paste within the Java application itself works fine).

My environment is OSX 10.9.2, JMeter 2.11 r1554548, java version "1.7.0_55".

This is the error you get every time you try and paste into the app from the system clipboard:

```
2014-05-06 08:32:52.363 java[22814:d07] *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
2014-05-06 08:32:52.364 java[22814:d07] (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e63f25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8b0b7e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e5006c7 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 951
        3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8eeb913e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 229
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e570731 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
        5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e561ea2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
        6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e56162f __CFRunLoopRun + 831
        7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e5610b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
        8   HIToolbox                           0x00007fff84fe3a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
        9   HIToolbox                           0x00007fff84fe37b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
        10  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff84fe35bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
        11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8856d3de _DPSNextEvent + 1434
        12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8856ca2b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
        13  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000011533c4e3 -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
        14  AppKit                              0x00007fff88560b2c -[NSApplication run] + 553
        15  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000011533c346 +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 156
        16  liblwawt.dylib                      0x0000000115bb7999 -[AWTStarter starter:] + 873
        17  Foundation                          0x00007fff8eeb913e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 229
        18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e570731 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
        19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e561ea2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
        20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e56162f __CFRunLoopRun + 831
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e5610b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
        22  java                                0x000000010a5183b0 CreateExecutionEnvironment + 871
        23  java                                0x000000010a512b5c JLI_Launch + 1952
        24  java                                0x000000010a51870d main + 101
        25  java                                0x000000010a5123b4 start + 52
        26  ???                                 0x0000000000000007 0x0 + 7
```

)

Comment: A stupid question, how do you paste text into JMeter ? through CMD+C or using Paste from menu ?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on JDK 14 and JMeter 5.4.3 is changing the Look and Feel settings to `System`.

`Options -> Look and Feel -> System`